# Оптимизация рисования на canvas JS

Tags: javascript

Я рисую на канвас большое кол-во квадратов примерно от 30 000 - 10 000 на кадр, с текущей реализацией, на рисование квадратов уходит от 30мс - 18мс. Что критично так-как о 60 fps, можно и не мечтать, так как еще время уходит на подсчет нового кадра(17мс - 25мс).

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const contextCanvas = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Отрисовка на канвас

```
const PrintMap = () =>{
    contextCanvas.clearRect(0,0, WIDHT, HEIGHT)
    contextCanvas.beginPath()
    for(let y = 1; y < HEIGHT - 1; y++)
        for(let x = 1; x < WIDHT - 1; x++)
        if(Map[x + y * WIDHT] == 1)
            contextCanvas.rect(
                x, y, 2, 2 );
         
    contextCanvas.fill()
    contextCanvas.closePath()
}
Массив Map[] - это одномерный массив в котором, хранится информация живая клетка или нет,
если клетка живая то я рисую квадрат, если же нет то ничего не рисую.

Массив Map[], обновляется каждый кадр, поэтому кол-во живых клеток уменьшается, 
как и кол-во рисуемых квадратов на canvas
```

Реализация анимации

```
const Frame = () =>{

NextGeneration() //Изменение массива Map[]
PrintMap()
requestFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(Frame)
}
```

Запускается отрисовка по нажатию кнопки

```
const Start = () =>{
    requestFrameId = requestAnimationFrame(Frame); 
}
```

Буду благодарен за предложения по оптимизации.

Примерно так выглядит один кадр анимации

Можете посмотреть более детально на текущей реализации:
https://vorobevvsevolod.github.io/gameoflife/

Ссылка на исходный код на github
https://github.com/vorobevvsevolod/gameoflife

[image: примерно так выглядит конечный результат]

Comment: а зачем там ArrayBuffer? тем более с неверным его использованием

Comment: Вопрос не про это, а про оптимизацию canvas. Насчёт  ArrayBuffer случайно попала с моих эксперементов с байтовыми массивами

Comment: в том числе и про это

Comment: еще один вопрос: зачем бежать по всем пикселям, если можно бежать просто по массиву `Map`? В худшем случае это конечно вернется к проходу по всем пикселям, но в среднем - будет меньше

Comment: WIDTH и HEIGHT как расти являются размером массивом. Тут я украсил код, но в самом проекте есть ещё resolution - разрешение оно как раз помогает делать массив меньше а сами пиксели больше, если вы зайдёте на сайт, там в настройках как раз есть ползунок и там реализовано то-то чем вы говорите, на самом большом resolution скорости очень большие из-за более меньшего массива

Comment: `contextCanvas.clearRect(0,0, WIDHT, HEIGHT)` - эта строчка говорит что width и height - это как раз размер canvas, а значит все возможные пиксели, это как раз избыточно в общем случае

Comment: Размер массива Map в два раза меньше чем размер канваса, получается что если я укажу размер массива  в crearRect. Но я очищу условно пол экрана а не весь. Картинка на канвас растягивается на всё разрешение. Например размер канвас 1920х1080.а размер массива 960х540, размер пикселей в 2 раза больше и получается что массив в ц раза меньше чем радмер экрана растягивается. Если очистить только по размерам массива, то я очищу ток часть экрана. (Уже проверено). И даже есть вообще убрать crearRect это не даёт практически никакого ускорение вывода

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140457/discussion-between-grundy-and-seva-vorobev).